# Output nested array with nr id in front of bracket

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, arrays, nested

I'm new with this stuff and I'm asking how can I do this example of nested arrays from MySQL table to output like this example of chats in javascript for node js express API, I'm using vue-cli.

See the `chats` Mysql Table:
[Mysql chat table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLzE4.png)

This is what im trying to achive:

```
 chats: {
 SENDER ID -> 1: {
          isPinned: true,
          msg: [
            { // this is me (sender)
              textContent: 'How can we help? We\'re here for you!',
              time: 'Mon Dec 10 2018 07:45:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)',
              isSent: true,
              isSeen: true
            },
            { // this is the receiver
              textContent: 'Hey John, I am looking for the best admin template. Could you please help me to find it out?',
              time: 'Mon Dec 10 2018 07:45:23 GMT+0000 (GMT)',
              isSent: false,
              isSeen: true
            } 
          ]
        },
        2: {
          isPinned: false,
          msg: [
            {
              textContent: 'Hi',
              time: 'Mon Dec 10 2018 07:45:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)',
              isSent: true,
              isSeen: true
            },
            {
              textContent: 'Hello. How can I help You?',
              time: 'Mon Dec 11 2018 07:45:15 GMT+0000 (GMT)',
              isSent: false,
              isSeen: true
            } 
          ]
        }
      }
```

This is what i have done until now:
Mysql query:

```
getChats: callBack => {
    pool.query(
      'SELECT * FROM chat WHERE reciever_userid=1 AND sender_userid=5 OR sender_userid=1 AND reciever_userid=5  ORDER BY time',
      [],
      (error, chats) => {
        if (error) {
          callBack(error)
        }
        return callBack(null, chats)
      }
    )
  }
```

Api call:

```
 getChats((err, chatz) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return
  }   

  const chats = chatz.map(el => { 
    el.msg = {
      textContent    : el.textContent   || null,
      time           : el.time          || null,
      isSent         : el.isSent        || null,
      isSeen         : el.isSeen        || null
    } 
    delete el['status'] 
    delete el['sender_userid'] 
    delete el['reciever_userid'] 
    delete el['textContent'] 
    delete el['time'] 
    delete el['isSent'] 
    delete el['isSeen'] 
    delete el['id'] 
    return el
  }).flat()
    
  return res.json({
    chats
  })
})
```

And the result in postman is not what I have looking for in the example above.

```
    {
    "chats": [
        {
            "isPinned": "true",
            "msg": {
                "textContent": "heyyy",
                "time": "2020-10-07T15:04:40.000Z",
                "isSent": "true",
                "isSeen": "true"
            }
        },
        {
            "isPinned": "true",
            "msg": {
                "textContent": "yesss",
                "time": "2020-10-07T15:04:40.000Z",
                "isSent": "true",
                "isSeen": "true"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: So the issue is you're getting chats as array instead of object with indexes? Or that msg is an object instead of an array? Or both?

Comment: I don;t know hot to output like in the example with 1: { in front

Comment: Ok, check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match your target format, change 'Api call' code to this:

```
getChats((err, chatz) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      return
    }   
  
    const chatsArray = chatz.map(el => { 
      el.msg = {
        textContent    : el.textContent   || null,
        time           : el.time          || null,
        isSent         : el.isSent        || null,
        isSeen         : el.isSeen        || null
      } 
      delete el['status'] 
      delete el['sender_userid'] 
      delete el['reciever_userid'] 
      delete el['textContent'] 
      delete el['time'] 
      delete el['isSent'] 
      delete el['isSeen'] 
      delete el['id'] 
      return el
    }).flat()

    let chats = {};
    chatsArray.forEach((chat, i) => chats[i + 1] = chat)
      
    return res.json({
      chats
    })
  })
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! Now i got the correct results.

Comment: One more thing, i see from your code results that all the textContent they are separate, all the textContent from id 1 and id 2 or 2 to 1 should be together as one, like in the achive example, is possible to achive that?